# How to wait for BackgroundWorker finish without getting the UI Freeze

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to code a simple file downloader. There are 4 or more files need to download one by one. I have used a backgroundWorker to avoid freeze the UI. And I have sent the first URL through a variable.

```
    Dim  crrDownloading as String
    dim URL1  as String = "https://example.com/download/file1.zip"
    dim URL2  as String = "https://example.com/download/file2.zip"
    dim URL3  as String = "https://example.com/download/file3.zip"
    dim URL4  as String = "https://example.com/download/file4.zip"    

Private Sub DownloadList()

    'Download 1st File
     StartDownload(URL1)

    'Download 2nd File
     StartDownload(URL2)

     ...

End Sub

Private Sub StartDownload(URL)

    If Not bwDownloader.IsBusy Then
            crrDownloading = URL
            bwDownloader.RunWorkerAsync()
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub bwDownloader_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bwDownloader.DoWork
    'web request code...

    theRequest = WebRequest.Create(crrDownloading)

    'more code...
End Sub
```

I want to download the next files after the `backgroundworker`download the current file.  What is the correct way to wait for the `backgroundworker` to finish there task?

Comment: You can use the async version of the WebRequest methods, create a method that returns a `Task` or a `Task(Of SomeType)`, add the Tasks to a `List(Of Task)` then just `await Task.WhenAll(YourListOfTasks)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's good to understand what's actually happening here. The `BackgroundWorker` isn't downloading any files. All the `BackgroundWorker` does is raise an event on a background thread. It's up to you to handle that event and then any code you put in your event handler is executed on that background thread. The event handler in your code is part of your form, so it's your form that's downloading the files, not the `BackgroundWorker`.

If you were going to stick with the `BackgroundWorker` then you would have two choices. Either you would download the files in serial, one after the other, or else you would download them in parallel, which would require one `BackgroundWorker` per file. Using multiple `BackgroundWorkers` is a little cumbersome, but the good thing is that you can use the same method to handle all the `DoWork` events. You would just pass in the URL when you call `RunWorkerAsync`. If you just use one `BackgroundWorker` then you would write a method that performs one download and then call that four times.

That said, it probably is better to go with the `Task` option suggested in the comments.

Comment: thank you for this detailed answer. With a one `backgroundWorker` should I use `RunWorkerCompleted` event or is there a better way to detect `backgroundWorker` is competed? I mean using a Timer to check repeatedly or something like that.

Comment: The `RunWorkerCompleted` event is the correct way to determine that the background work has completed. You could, if you wanted, call `RunWorkerAsync` again from the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler to download one file at a time but that would be unnecessarily complex when just one call to download all files would be simpler.